# How to isolate low voltage control circuit from high voltage power circuit?

Tags: oscillator, isolation

Can anyone give me a brief run-down of some methods I could use for this?

[image]

I want to drive a MOSFET or BJT with a 12v 555 circuit or oscillator.  The MOSFET will drive a high voltage circuit that can have both large positives and large negatives occuring on both sides of the transistor.  As a result, a MOSFET will require a floating voltage divider to ensure the gate isn't destroyed.  But that won't ensure that my control circuitry is protected.

I'm pretty sure that I really need to completely electrically isolate the control circuitry if possible.  Can anyone throw out some common techniques so I have an idea of ways to go about it? I need this to operate between 50kHz and 800kHz.

Comment: I'd use a solid state relay.  There is a good chance that a MOSFET won't survive due to the reverse body diode inside the MOSFET-- but I can't say for certain given the lack of information in the question.

Comment: David, I think I read this somewhere before but forgot about it.  You're saying there are limitations in how much reverse current the body diode can conduct. Is that right?

Comment: The reverse body diode is a crappy diode.  Slow, inefficient, large Vf, etc.  If the properties of the diode is even remotely important then put a real diode in parallel with it.

Comment: David, I'm looking at the datasheet for my mosfet and it shows the same reverse body diode current as the regular forward drain current.
http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00039392.pdf

I'll definitely consider the real diode in parallel.  I suppose if I use a real diode with a lower voltage bias then it should kick in first and carry most of the current.

Comment: Look closely.  Forward on voltage is a terrible 1.5v, and the reverse recovery time is 85 ns.  Depending on your app, the reverse recovery current might also be an issue for you.  While the source-drain-current is 180A, if you actually had that much current flowing then you would be dissipating 270 watts!

Comment: You could have the control circuit floated to the gate and source of the FET by using a battery or an isolated DC-to-DC convertor. If you use a DC2DC then you'll have to find one with low capacitance to ground to prevent the AC voltages on the source of the FET driving currents through it. How are you going to control the reverse polarity situation with the FET or are you not too bothered?

Comment: David, i may help if you answer my questions,                   1)can you post the rough sketch of your design(its hard to find out whether you are using half bridge or full bridge). 2)Which MOSFET?(power rating,current) 3)what type of load(inductive or resistive) 4)what is the maximum and minimum duty cycle of the 50KHZ-800KHZ signal

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly the application optocouplers are made for.

Optocouplers consist of a LED on one side and a photodiode or a phototransistor on the other side. Both are put into one package but are kept well insulated from each other.

The electrical signal is transformed into light by the LED and back into an electrical signal by the photodiode/phototransistor.